# Cambiar color de una fila de una tabla html dependiendo de un valor

Tags: php, css, html-tabla

estoy tratando de cambiar el color de una fila de mi tabla html, dependiendo del valor de una celda, pero al actualizar la página observo los colores que les pongo pasa 1 segundo aprox. y estos colores desaparecen, estoy usando Chrome.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

#### PHP/HTML:

```
<tbody>
                            <?php
                            $array_causa_colores = array(
                                'Por determinar' => 'green',
                                'Problema con el enlace de proveedor' => 'yellow'
                            );
                            ?>
                        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                            
                            
                            <tr class= "<?php echo $array_causa_colores[$row['causa']];?>"> 
                                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['alcance']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['tecnologia']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['serv_afectados']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['zona']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['inicio']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['fin']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['ticket']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['causa']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['solicitud']; ?></td>
                                <td><a href="modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" data-href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
                            </tr>
```

#### CSS:

```
.green{background-color: green;}
.yellow{background-color: yellow;}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Conviene que pongas otras partes del código que falta. Algo ocurre después de mostrar la tabla que hace que los colores desaparezcan, por lo tanto debes mostrar el código sub-siguiente. ¿Sólo desaparecen los colores o también la tabla desaparece?

Comment: En Chrome puedes usar las teclas Ctrl-shift-I para ver los elementos HTML y demás. Accede a la etiqueta tr de HTML con la flecha y comprueba si ha perdido la clase green o yellow, o si hay algún style con background-color que manda sobre la clase.
El código es correcto, hay alguna clase, javascript o estilo que sobreescribe al del código de PHP.

Answer (score 1):

te voy a plantear una opción que creo va a ser más ordenada, suponiendo que puede tener dos colores.

En base a esto en tu **tr** creo que es mejor aplicar una clase dependiendo de este campo que traes para aplicar un color u otro, voy a poner un ejemplo:

Suponiendo que quieras pintar tu **tr** cuando la variable te devuelve el valor 1:

```
<tr class=" <?php echo ($row['fin']==1)?'color-verde':'sin-color' ?>"</tr>
```

pregunto si el valor de **$row['fin']** es igual a 1, si es así se aplica una etiqueta que se va a llamar *color-verde*, si no es 1, 'sin-color'

faltaría agregar una propiedad en css para dale el color que tu quieras.

```css
.color-verde{
  background:green;
}
```

Ojalá te sirva, saludos

Answer (score 0):

ante todo gracias por tomarse el tiempo en poder revisarlo, disculpen la demora he estado viendo otras cosas y habia dejado de lado este tema. He probado poniendo de otra forma y no logra, tal ve le pueda compartir todo el codigo para esa parte de la página, he quitado el link para los estilos css y se comporta igual, cuando refrescas la pagina al inicio se observa con los colores que puse y luego de 1 segundo cambia todo blanco.

```
<?php

session_start();

//echo $_SESSION['aut'];

if ($_SESSION['aut']!='SI'){

                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location='login.html'; </script>";

}











                require 'conexion.php';



                $sql = "SELECT * FROM notifi_afectacion ORDER BY id DESC";

                $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

                $numfilas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);



                $abiertas= "SELECT * FROM notifi_afectacion where Fin= ''";

                $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($abiertas);

                $numfilasabiertas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado2);



?>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">



                <head>

                               <title>NOTIFICACIONES NOC</title>



                               <meta charset="utf-8">

                               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

                               <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

                               <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                               <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

                               <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

                               <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

                               <link href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

                               <link href="estiloformulario2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



                               <script>

                                               $(document).ready(function(){

                                                               $('#tabla1').DataTable({

                                                                              "order": [[0, "desc"]],

                                                                              "language":{

                                                                                              "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",

                                                                                              "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",

                                                                                              "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",

                                                                                              "infoFiltered": "(filtrada de _MAX_ registros)",

                                                                                              "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",

                                                                                              "processing":     "Procesando...",

                                                                                              "search": "Buscar:",

                                                                                              "zeroRecords":    "No se encontraron registros coincidentes",

                                                                                              "paginate": {

                                                                                                              "next":       "Siguiente",

                                                                                                              "previous":   "Anterior"

                                                                                              },                                                                          

                                                                              }

                                                               });          

                                               });          

                               </script>

                </head>



                <body>

                                               <header>

                                                               <div class="wraper">

                                                                              <div class="logo">

                                                                                              <a href="#"><img src="entel3.jpg"></a>

                                                                              </div>



                                                                              <nav>

                                                                                              <a href="Notificacion.php" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span> Nueva Notificación</a>

                                                                                              <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>   Home</a>

                                                                                              <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-salir"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Salir</a>

                                                                              </nav>

                                                               </div>

                                               </header>



                               <div class="container">

                                               <div class="titulo">

                                                               <h2 style="text-align:center">Notificaciones de Afectación de Servicio</h2><br><br>

                                               </div>



                                               <br><br>



                                               <div class="row" id=cantidad>

                                                               <p><?php

                                                                                               echo  "Notificaciones por cerrar  = ".$numfilasabiertas ;

                                                                              ?></p>

                                               </div>



                                               <br><br>

                                               <div class="table-responsive" id="">

                                                               <table class="display table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" id="tabla1" style="font-size:13px">



                                                                              <thead>

                                                                                              <tr>

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 1%">ID</th>

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 5%">Zona Geográfica</th>

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 10%">Alcance de la Falla</th>                                                          

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 9%">Inicio</th>

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 9%">Fin</th>

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 5%">Ticket</th>

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 13%">Causa</th>

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 13%">Solicitud de Cierre</th>

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 3%">Editar</th>

                                                                                                              <th style="width: 3%">Eliminar</th>

                                                                                              </tr>

                                                                              </thead>



                                                                              <tbody>

                                                                                              <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>





                                                                                                              <tr bgcolor="<?php if ($row['fin']=="") echo '#F9CD0B';else echo '#40DC3' ?>" >

                                                                                                                             <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>

                                                                                                                             <td><?php echo $row['zona']; ?></td>

                                                                                                                             <td><?php echo $row['alcance']; ?></td>                                                                                                      

                                                                                                                             <td><?php echo $row['inicio']; ?></td>

                                                                                                                             <td><?php echo $row['fin']; ?></td>

                                                                                                                             <td><?php echo $row['ticket']; ?></td>

                                                                                                                             <td><?php echo $row['causa']; ?></td>

                                                                                                                             <td><?php echo $row['solicitud']; ?></td>

                                                                                                                             <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>

                                                                                                                             <td style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" data-href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>

                                                                                                              </tr>

                                                                                              <?php } ?>



                                                                              </tbody>

                                                               </table><br><br>

                                               </div>



                               </div>



                               <!-- Modal -->

                               <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                                               <div class="modal-dialog">

                                                               <div class="modal-content">



                                                                              <div class="modal-header">

                                                                                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                                                                                              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar Registro</h4>

                                                                              </div>



                                                                              <div class="modal-body">

                                                                                              ¿Desea eliminar este registro?

                                                                              </div>



                                                                              <div class="modal-footer">

                                                                                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                                                                                              <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>

                                                                              </div>

                                                               </div>

                                               </div>

                               </div>



                               <script>

                                               $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

                                                               $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));



                                                               $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');

                                               });

                               </script>            

                               <footer>

                                               <div class="wrapp">

                                                               <p> 2019</p>

                                               </div>



                               </footer>

                </body>



</html>
```

Comment: Daniel, bienvenido a SOes. Has creado otra cuenta para publicar esta respuesta? Te recomiendo eliminar alguna de las dos cuentas y usar las funciones de edicion que tiene el sitio si en caso deseas agregar mas informacino.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo, una situacion similar.

La fila en mi codigo esta así:

```
<tr class="micolor" bgcolor="rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.3)">
  <td>valor 1</td>
  <td>valor 1</td>
</tr>
```

pero en el navegador queda así:

```
<tr class="micolor odd" bgcolor="rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.3)" role="row">
  <td>valor 1</td>
  <td>valor 1</td>
</tr>
```

en el css aplico:

```
.micolor{
   background:green;
}
```

pero no funciona, porque la fila supongo aplica el estilo a la class="odd" que sobreescribe mi estilo.

Como se puede sobreescribir o suplantar el estilo para class="odd" dejando que sea class="micolor" el que quede?